# Can't login with Mac mail smtp can't /send or receive emails with dovecot/postfix

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I set everything up following guides. Every test I run tells me it's all working but I can't log in with Mac mail with `-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes` when I turn this to no I can log in with Mac mail but still cannot send or receive emails any help would be greatly appreciated this my 5th day trying to set this mail server up with no joy.

This is postfix master.cf:

```
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Here is my main.cf:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                 /etc/postfix/main.cf                                                                                            
smtp_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_session_cache_database =
    btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtp_tls_session_cache

# SMTP from other servers to yours
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ibizasoundevent.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = //etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ibizasoundevent.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database =
    btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
smtpd_tls_ccert_verifydepth = 2

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.ibizasoundevent.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = ibizasoundevent.com
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_protocols = ipv4
mynetworks_style = subnet
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mydomain = ibizasoundevent.com
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = ibizasoundevent.com
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination reject_invalid_hostname reject_non_fqdn_hostname reject_non_fqdn_sender reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_>
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,reject_invalid_helo_hostname,reject_unknown_helo_hostname
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_tls_req_ccert = yes
```

Here is my dovecot config:

```
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.7.2 ()
# OS: Linux 5.4.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 
# Hostname: ibizasoundevent.com
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = maildir:~/Maildir
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = %s
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ibizasoundevent.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Comment: Try to send a test email and then check the mail logs to check for errors. If you do find any errors add them to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it connected to macmail now and i can send an email. from there and receive on the other end.  problem now is i cant receive emails
but the email server did get the reply so it can send and receive but in mac mail it can only send
this is my mail log 
any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Follow your maillogs and filter for dovecot. I don't know where ubuntu keeps the maillogs but do something like this 
`tail -f /var/log/maillog | grep -i dovecot --line-buffer` then try to login to your mail server using your  macmail client and see if there are any errors